# 200 website code by Console

Tags: seo, wordpress, web-crawlers, search, yoast

Can someone help me and let me know why google is not ranking quite some few of my sites from mine latest SEO project:

https://kroatien-ferienwohnungen.at/

I see that plenty of pages are crawled but only few indexed. Most of my blog posts are not visible on Google.[image]

Comment: Please read indexing issues. https://digitalsetups.com/site-indexing-issues/ (a resource published by me for my community, clients, and students).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this issues, and here are the 3 things you can do to resolve this:

1. You have not set up **INSTANT INDEXING API**. I see that you
   are using WordPress, therefore I suggest you do this setup in
   addition https://rankmath.com/blog/google-indexing-api/ . This is to
   ensure that each of your pages or hundred of pages/posts can be submitted to Google Search Console via API in a second.
2. The **contents** on the domain are considered low quality, and the
   competition in the search result in your niche is competitive, which
   makes your site not indexed in the top 100 in search results, for instance.
   Therefore review your **content quality** to meet the Search Engine's content
   guideline.
3. Create a small number of backlinks to your internal pages to **add some link juices** for the overall domain score.